# Issue executing function when selecting and deselecting rows in tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview

NOTE: TableView is populated using JSON with the structure containing the value codeNum

I need to execute two different functions based on if a row is being selected or unselected, the following the is the selection mechanism I have in place:

```
class CheckableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
    }
}
```

When a row is selected `select()` needs to run and when a row unselected `unselect()` needs to run. Before this is done the rows codeNum value needs to be assigned to the variable tappedSelected:

```
    structure = sections[indexPath.section].items
    let theStructure = structure[indexPath.row]
    tappedSelected = theStructure.codeNum
```

How can this be implemented into the custom class?

Comment: Where do you have select() and unselect() methods? In ViewController or in TableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using didSelectRowAt() and didDeselectRowAt() methods. Assuming that multiple selections are allowed here is how I would do it.

## If cell is selected

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    structure = sections[indexPath.section].items
    let theStructure = structure[indexPath.row]
    tappedSelected = theStructure.codeNum
    select(tappedSelected)
}
```

## If cell is unselected

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    structure = sections[indexPath.section].items
    let theStructure = structure[indexPath.row]
    tappedSelected = theStructure.codeNum
    unselect(tappedSelected)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closures to call the methods upon select/deselect the cell.

First of all, create a `closure` in your `CheckableTableViewCell` and call it with `true/false` in `setSelected(_:animated:)` method, i.e.

```
class CheckableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var handler: ((Bool)->())? //here....

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
        handler?(selected) //here....
    }

    //rest of the code....
}
```

Next, in your `ViewController`, set the value of `handler` for `CheckableTableViewCell` instance in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method, i.e.

```
 class VC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    //rest of the code...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CheckableTableViewCell
        cell.handler = {[weak self](selected) in
            selected ? self?.select(indexPath) : self?.unselect()
        }
        return cell
    }

    func select(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let structure = sections[indexPath.section].items
        let theStructure = structure[indexPath.row]
        tappedSelected = theStructure.codeNum
    }

    func unselect() {
        //add the code here...
    }
}
```

This will resolve your issue of calling `select()` or `unselect()` methods when the cell is selected or unselected.

For your another requirement, please clarify at what point you want to set `codeNum` value to `tappedSelected`. And where does `tappedSelected` exist, in `ViewController` or in `CheckableTableViewCell`.

Comment: tappedSelected is a variable that will contain the value of codeNum once a row is selected. I am using it in functions select() and unselect()

Comment: Please let me know if you have other questions

Comment: Well, in that case you can write the same code like you did earlier in `select()` method.

Comment: Are you referring to “structure = sections...” for both select() and unselect()?

Comment: I also noticed when testing your code, unselect() kept being executed when the TableViewController first ran

Comment: Should unselect() get the same thing?

Comment: The unselect() function also uses this info

Comment: Doing structure = sections... in select() gives me the error `Use of unresolved identifier 'indexPath`

Comment: I made a few slight adjustments and it does work now, but when scrolling the checkmarks disappear, how can this be prevented?

Comment: You need to store the selected state somewhere in the model and use that to show the checkmarks.

Comment: Do accept (tick on left) if the answer helped. Happy coding 

Comment: If possible can you please show me how this can be done? I would really appreciate it, that is the last thing I am struggling with